# analogRead takes too much time

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I've made a basic waveform generator with an Arduino Uno and a resistor ladder on a breadboard. I change the voltage level as needed using the `loop` function and `micros()` to delay between each voltage change. It's not perfect but it works well with a piezo.

My problem is I set the signal frequency in my code and I would like to be able to change it using a pot for example. But as soon as I put an `analogRead` somewhere in my code (all the code is in the `loop()` function) the output signal changes. I found out that the `analogRead` function can take up to 100µs to run, and that's greater than the delay between each voltage change so the actual signal period is not correct:

```
unsigned long now, next;
int freq;

void loop(){
    
    //if I put analogRead() here it takes to much time

    now = micros();

    if(now >= next){
        //Here I change the output analog value using a R-2R ladder
        //then I change the value of next 
    }
}
```

I tried a few solutions including using switches instead of a pot but `digitalRead` combined with if statement don't seem more efficient. I also tried switches with interrupts but the result is the same as with `digitalRead`.

Does somebody know another solution?

Comment: could you please provide a description of your *interrupt-based attempt*? it seems to me that pushing your output handling out of *loop()* into an *interrupt service routine* should be the way to go.. this should allow you to use `analogRead()` without altering the signal, which would still take precedence thanks to being handled with *interrupts*.. or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The `analogRead` waits until conversion is done, so if you want to do something else, you have to handle it differently.

You can use ADC interrupt and free running mode. Or you can trigger the ADC conversion cycle by several sources like timer compare.

Or you can do it by "event" based approach - by checking that ADC conversion is done and reset it by writing logic one to that flag.

```
// in setup:
ADCSRA |= _BV(ADATE); // enable auto trigger mode 
ADCSRB = 0; // free running mode for the auto trigger

// and in the loop:
if (ADCSRA & _BV(ADIF)) {
    value = ADC; // get ADC value
    ADCSRA |= _BV(ADIF); // reset flag by writing logic one into it
    // whatever you want with the current value
    // or  ADCSRA |= _BV(ADSC); // start another conversion if you don't want free running mode
}
```

Btw: macro `_BV(BIT)` is replaced to  `1<<(BIT)` (if you wonder why I'm using it)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll test it but I guess it takes less time than the Arduino's analogRead